# Checking if input from a form is in table django

Tags: python, django

The goal is to take in input from a user and see if that input matches information in a table in a database.  If there is a match, delete that information from the table.  If there isn't a match, clear out the form and say that there isn't a match.

Here is the views file.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import CheckoutForm, CheckoutRegForm
from .models import Checkout
from books.models import Addbook

def checkout(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CheckoutForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'The book has been checked out.')
            return redirect('front-page')
    else:
        form = CheckoutForm()
        return render(request, 'checkout/checkout.html', {'form': form})

def checkin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CheckoutRegForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            member_id = form.cleaned_data['member_id']
            if title in Checkout.objects.all():
                Checkout.objects.filter(title = title).delete()
                messages.success(request, f'The book has been checked in.')
                return redirect('front-page')
            else:
                messages.error(request, f'Error:  This book is not in the Checkout table.')
                return redirect('checkin')

    else:
        form = CheckoutRegForm()
        return render(request, 'checkout/checkin.html', {'form': form})
```

From my understanding, forms in Django collect user information and store it in a dictionary 'form.cleaned_data'.  I tired multiple ways to set up that if statement to see if there is a match with the input from the user and information in the Checkout table.  But no matter how I set up the if statement, it seems to always go to the 'else' part whenever I test it out. So basically even when I type a title that I know is in the checkout table, it doesn't get deleted and it gives me the error message of "This book is not in the Checkout table".

Here is my forms.py

```
from .models import Checkout
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms

class CheckoutForm(ModelForm):
#    member_id = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Checkout
        fields = [
            'title',
            'member_id',
        ]

class CheckoutRegForm(forms.Form):
    member_id = forms.IntegerField()
    title = forms.CharField(max_length = 1000)
#    date_checkout = forms.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

Ignore the comments.  Here is the modules file if you need that.

```
from django.db import models

class Checkout(models.Model):
    member_id = models.IntegerField(null = True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
    date_checkout = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

Thanks for any help.  If you need any other information or not really sure what I'm asking, just let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in

> if title in Checkout.objects.all():

Checkout.objects.all() will return list of objects, when U compare string data from your form. So it's must be something like that:

```
for object in Checkout.objects.all():
    if object.title == title:
        do something...
```

Comment: Thanks!  This works perfectly and I see the mistake now.